# How to pass class variables in redux store and action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement Google Authentication using GAPI and I want to store the userId of the user fetched by GAPI into the redux store. I don't know how to pass class component variables into a redux store or action dispatcher. Can someone please help me out to get out of this?

```
    import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from './types'
    export const signIn = (dispatch, userId) => {
        console.log('actions',userId)
        dispatch(
            {
                type: SIGN_IN,
                payload:userId
            }
        )
    }

    export const signOut = (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(
            {
                type: SIGN_OUT
            }
        )
    }
```

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
        return {
            isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
      
        return {
            SignIn: () => signIn(dispatch),
            SignOut: () => signOut(dispatch)
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GoogleAuth);
```

Answer (score 0):

> SignIn: () => signIn(dispatch,ownProps.toString()),

I think it's should be

> SignIn: (value) => signIn(dispatch, value),

Comment: How to pass the value

Comment: Cause SignIn function is instead of function you created in Action "export const signIn = (dispatch, userId)", and you must pass userId from somewhere to this.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do i want to pass userId to action

Comment: where you get userId value and calling function SignIn??? I think you should post all related to here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value when you actually dispatch an action. once you have the user id you do

```
this.props.SignIn(userId)
```

this will fire action dispatch where you have to pass value like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {

return {
    SignIn: (id) => signIn(dispatch,id),
    SignOut: () => signOut(dispatch)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const signIn = (userId) => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN,
        payload: userId
    };
};

export const signOut = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_OUT
    };
};
```

For your GoogleAuth Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        window.gapi.client.init({
            clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'email'
        }).then(() => {
            this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();    //Assign the auth instance
            this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());      //Update the auth state in store
            this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);     //Wait for the auth state to change in future
        });
    });
}

onAuthChange = (isSignedIn) => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
    } else {
        this.props.signOut();
    }
};
const mapsStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn };
}

export default connect(mapsStateToProps, { signIn, signOut })(GoogleAuth);
```